# Software the lets you build jquery animation in a GUI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Is there a software that let's you build Javascript (jquery) animation in a GUI? I think one example of what i mean is Adobe Edge. What are some good alternative on this?

Animation i kinda like would be something like this. www.apple.com/iphone/

Thanks!